Proving triangle inequality on integers through alternative method
Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, it's well known that $|n| = \prod_{p \ prime} \frac{1}{|n|_p}$, where $|n|_p$ is the p-adic absolute value.
Is there anyway to prove the triangle inequality on the usual absolute value, directly through this equality? Specifically, I wouldn't want to separate into cases that depend on the signs of $n$ and $m$.
It can be noted that given $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n+m = gcd(n, m)\left(\frac{n}{gcd(n, m)} + \frac{m}{gcd(n, m)}\right)$, so we can suppose without loss of generality that $n$ and $m$ are coprime.
